# UWP form Start Menu VB.Net Drag and Drop

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, uwp, drag-and-drop

I am trying to "Drag & Drop" icons from the Start Menu in windows 10 to get it's Target; Naturally this works with .lnk but when dealing with a UWP it's not actually a .lnk (as far as I know). FileName, FileNameW and FileDrop is always "Nothing"

Can anyone think of a way (even if it is creating a shortcut in the application path and saving that and getting that "Target" path instead) of getting the Target of a UWP dragged onto the form (Windows Form) in VB.net or C# ; Either is fine.

I have tried everything I can think of and just can't seem to find documentation or create any logic to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

This works if anyone else needs it. It is a clear easy method and works perfect.

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell
```

Then on DragEnter

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent("Shell IDList Array") Then
e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect
End If
```

Then on DragDrop

```
Dim ShellObj = ShellObjectCollection.FromDataObject(e.Data)
For Each itm As ShellObject In ShellObj
' here is where you add what you want to parse the information to 
'like last time I am passing the information to labels and then listbox
'App Name ("Friendly Name")
Label3.Text = itm.Name
'App ID
Label4.Text = itm.ParsingName
'Install Path
Label5.Text = itm.Properties.GetProperty("System.AppUserModel.PackageInstallPath").ValueAsObject

Next
End Sub
```

Obvs you can pass the results anywhere you wanted I just used labels for simplicity in explanation.